# A closed form for the coefficients of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials are defined recursively:
$T_0(x)=1$;
$T_1(x)=x$;
$T_n(x)=2xT_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x)$

I have been trying to find a closed form for the coefficient on the monomial $x^j$ of the $k$th polynomial. I denote this as $c_{k,j}$. I think it is clear that the $c_{k,j}$ satisfy the recurrence:
$c_{k,j}=2c_{k-1,j-1}-c_{k-2,j}$, but I am unsure of how to evaluate this double-indiced recurrence. Can anyone come up with the closed form? Is this result already known?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions) gives some forms, but probably needs a lot of manipulation for what you want. May I ask why you want the monomial coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients are given [here](http://oeis.org/A008310). See the section on the formula:

`a(n,m)=2^(m-1)*n*(-1)^[(n-m)/2]*[(n+m)/2-1]!/{[(n-m)/2]! m!} if n>0. - R. J. Mathar, Apr 20 2007`

Comment: Just be careful - that OEIS sequence ignores the zero coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find coefficients of Chebyshov polynomials two ways
via recurrence relation and via ordinary differential equation 
Recurrence relation approach lead you to following sum
$$T_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k{n \choose 2m}\cdot {m \choose k} \cdot x^{n-2k}$$
so
$$\mathrm{coeff}(T_{n}(x),n-2k)=\sum_{m=k}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k{n \choose 2m}\cdot {m \choose k}$$
If you are able to calculate this sum you will get your closed form for coefficients 
In ordinary differential equation approach you should get coefficients expressed in terms of a product

All coefficients require following product

$$\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\prod_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}(k-2m+n)(k-2m-n)$$

After using initial conditions for equation

$$(1-t^2)y'' -ty' + n^2y=0$$

and calculating product

$$\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\prod_{m=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}(k-2m+n)(k-2m-n)$$

you will get closed form for the coefficients

I played with solution from ode and i have got following formula
for coefficients

$$\mathrm{coeff}(T_{n}(x),m)=\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}}{m!}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^n\right)\left(1+\left(-1\right)^m\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\left(-1\right)^n\right)\left(1-\left(-1\right)^m\right)n\right)\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor}{\left(m-2k-n\right)\left(m-2k+n\right)}$$